# R does not recognize variable as numeric

Tags: r, class, numeric

I am completely new to R and struggle with the class of my variable "Clarity1". I have coded it as numeric, but when I try to get the means for it (filtered and grouped by the categorical variable "Location"), I get "NA" and an error saying that it is not numeric. When checking with the class() function, it confirms that "Clarity1" is in fact numeric. Here is my code. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```r
Values_recoded$Clarity1 <- as.numeric(Values_recoded$Clarity1)
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): Objekt 'Values_recoded' nicht gefunden
class(Values_recoded$Clarity1)
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): Objekt 'Values_recoded' nicht gefunden

Values_recoded %>%
  filter(Location %in% c(1,3)) %>%
  group_by(Location)%>%
  mean(Clarity1, na.rm=TRUE)
#> Error in Values_recoded %>% filter(Location %in% c(1, 3)) %>% group_by(Location) %>% : konnte Funktion "%>%" nicht finden
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `class`, use

```r
typeof(Values_recoded$Clarity1)
```

to see the type.
Further, you need to load in a package like `library(tidyr)` for `%>%` to work.
If you want to find the mean, use

```r
summarise(mean = mean(Clarity1))
```

to help you further I would need a minimal working example with your data.